# Pandas Dataframe - multiply column by a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I am trying to identify columns that contain the letter 'k', remove 'k' from the star rating column and multiply the result by 5.

When I multiply, instead of multiplying the column value, the value is repeated 5 times.

I've tried multiplying in other ways (use numpy, use * to multiply) but am getting the same result.

Any suggestions? Image of code: [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kriXx.jpg)]

```
df_starrating ['StarRating'] = ['1.1k stars','900 stars','2.5k stars']

df_starrating['StarRating'] = df_starrating['StarRating'].str.replace('stars','')

if df_starrating['StarRating'].str.contains('k').any():
df_starrating['StarRating'] = df_starrating['StarRating'].str.replace('k','')
df_starrating['StarRating'] = df_starrating['StarRating'].multiply(5,axis = 'index')
```

Output:

1.1k, 1.1k, 1.1k, 1.1k, 1.1k

900,900,900,900,900

2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5

Comment: Don't post images. Post the code. And give an example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.apply(function)` method. Something like this should work:

```
def reformat(s):
    if s.find('k')!=-1
        s=s.replace('k', '')
return float(s)*5

df_starrating['StarRating'] = df_starrating['StarRating'].apply(reformat)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are multiplying a string. Try converting to a float first
e.g.

```py
df_starrating['StarRating'] = df_starrating['StarRating'].astype(float).multiply(5,axis = 'index')
```

Comment: Converting it to float resolved the multiplication issue but '900 stars' is also being multiplied, which is not what I am looking for.

Multiplying by 10 instead of 5 for simplicity's sake:
Updated code:
if df_starrating['StarRating'].str.contains('k').any():
    df_starrating['StarRating'] = df_starrating['StarRating'].str.replace('k','')
    df_starrating['StarRating'] = df_starrating['StarRating'].astype(float) * 10

Desired output:

11

900

25

Current output:

11

9000

25